# Refer to a row under a certain value, while keeping a filter on

Tags: r

I want to calculate two kinds of stock return:

Crisis return, defined as the return between the stock price on the first day and the lowest price in a given year (here: 2000).

Rebound return, defined as the return between the lowest price in the same year (so the same "Min(Price)" as above) and the stock price 6 months (or 120 obersvations) after this minimum (that could also be a price in the year 2001).

I was already able to calculate the crisis return with this code:

```
Crisis_Return <- Stock_prices %>% 
 group_by(PERMNO) %>% 
 filter("2000-12-29" >= date) %>% 
 summarise(Crisis_Return2 = min(Adj.Price)/Adj.Price[day==1]-1)
```

but have trouble with the rebound return.

I have a datafrem ("stock.prices") looking something like this:

```
PERMNO   date      Adj.Price   day

10001   2000-03-13   5.208333   1
10001   2000-03-13   5.25000    2 
10002   2000-03-13   7.12318    1
```

And tried to calculate the rebound return like this:

```
Rebound_Return <- Stock_prices %>% 
 group_by(PERMNO) %>%
 summarise(Rebound_Return2 = Adj.Price[which(min[Adj.Price]) + 120] /  min(Adj.Price)-1)
```

But that only gave me an error:

> Error in min[Adj.Price] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable.

Plus in this code the `filter` for the `Min(Adj.Price)` of the year 2000 is missing, I don't know how to incorporate it.

So the expected output would be a dataframe with a rebound return for each permno, with the return calculated bewteen the minimum price in the year 2000 and the stock price 120 obersavtions (or 6 months) after this `min(Adj.Price)`.

Answer (score 0):

With `which.min` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

Stock_prices %>%
   group_by(PERMNO) %>%
   summarise(Crisis_return = min(Adj.Price)/Adj.Price[day == 1] -1, 
              Rebound_Return = Adj.Price[which.min(Adj.Price) + 120]/min(Adj.Price) -1)
```

Assuming you have 120 rows of data after minimum of `Adj.Price` in each `PERMNO`.

Comment: Thank your suggestion. While this certainly produces some results, it does not garantuee, that the minimum is within a certain time period (=within the year 2000).
How do I make sure, that only the minimum is in the year 2000, while the price 6 months after this return doesnt have to be?
With the filter function? How to I incorporate it into the formula? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Kardeshma so if the output is outside the time period what output should that `PERMNO` give ? 0 ?

Comment: No. What I mean is: I want the minium be within the time period, so I would set a filter here. But i dont want the filter to be usd to the command "search for stock price 120 days / observations later". If I just put the ``filter```function in front of the code like I did above, the filter would refer to the whole formula, instead of just the min function.
The output should still be a regular return.